# how to get keyframe animation to stop at final stage

Tags: css

with the css:

```
.show-left-menu {
  -webkit-animation-name: leftSidebarAni;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .25s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes leftSidebarAni {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(84%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(79%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

how do i get a div with a class of 'show-left-menu' to stay at the final (100%) stage?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to the `.show-left-menu` CSS.

CSS:

```
.show-left-menu{
    -webkit-animation-name: leftSidebarAni;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .25s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```